# Im trying to direct to a page from a navbar where that page will act as a find page. but the page wont display anything

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route

`Route::get('/rating/find', 'RatingController@find');`

This is the navbar to direct to the page

```
<li class = "nav-item">
  <a class = "nav-link" href ="/rating/find">Planet Dive</a>
</li>
```

This is the rating controller with `find()` method

```
public function find()    
{
  return view('rating.find');
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `find` page?  Do you have a `RatingController`?  Does it have a `find()` method?  What is it returning?  Need a lot more information in your question to be able to help you.

Comment: probably because the '/' before rating/find uri

Answer (score 0):

Give your route a name

```
Route::get('rating/find', 'RatingController@find')->name('rating.find');
```

Then use `route()` helper method instead of static URI

```
<a class="nav-link" href ="{{ route('rating.find') }}"></a>
```